# invalid relational operator in SQL

Tags: oracle, operator-keyword, relational

```
select
create_date
,resolved_date
,to_char(create_date, 'YYYY') as year_create
,to_char(create_date, 'MM') as month_create
,to_char(create_date, 'WW') as week_create
,to_char(create_date,'Q') as quarter_create
,to_char(resolved_date, 'YYYY') as year_resolved
,to_char(resolved_date, 'MM') as month_resolved
,to_char(resolved_date, 'WW') as week_resolved
,to_char(resolved_date,'Q') as quarter_resolved
,item
,site
,status
,contact_time
,impact_label

from mytable

where
create_date between to_date('2013/03/01','YYYY/MM/DD') and to_date('2015/08/06','YYYY/MM/DD')
and case item 
when '1' then 'a'
when '2' then 'b'
when '3' then 'c'
else null 
end 

group by
create_date
,resolved_date
,to_char(create_date, 'YYYY') 
,to_char(create_date, 'MM') 
,to_char(create_date, 'WW') 
,to_char(create_date,'Q') 
,to_char(resolved_date, 'YYYY') 
,to_char(resolved_date, 'MM') 
,to_char(resolved_date, 'WW') 
,to_char(resolved_date,'Q') 
,item
,site
,status
,contact_time
,impact_label

order by item, site, create_date;
```

Can someone please help me spot the error of

> invalid relational operator

(it says at group by line). I don't see where I possibly left out `><= ?`

Comment: First, why do you have a `group by` clause at all?  It doesn't appear that you're doing any aggregation.  Second, in your `where` clause, you have a `case` statement but you're not comparing the result of that statement to anything.  I have no idea what you're trying to accomplish with that `case` statement so it's hard to guess what you intended.

Comment: 1. I thought group by is neccessary for any cases, if not, I could try to remove it. 2. In my case statement, I'm trying to generate different results for my item column, so if it has a result of 1 -> it will show a instead... This is actually not my case statement, I just made up an example of it. Thanks!

Comment: A `group by` is only used when you want to group rows together and aggregate data.  It sounds like you can remove the `group by`.  If you want the `case` statement to change what is presented, you'd want that to be in the `select` clause as an additional column in the projection not in the `where` clause.

Comment: http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/group_by.php isn't group by necessary for NOT aggregrate function?

Comment: No.  You use a `group by` when your query includes an aggregate function on some columns.  Otherwise, there is no point to grouping the rows.  You can include a `group by` without an aggregate function.  It just slows the query down for no reason and makes it more painful to support.

Comment: `where case item when '1' then 'a' when '2' then 'b' when '3' then 'c' else  null  end` is not a valid expression you can use in the `where` clause. You need to compare the result of that expression to something. e.g.  `where case ... end = 'a'`

Answer (score 2):

your case is not well structured. Try this :

```
SELECT create_date,
         resolved_date,
         TO_CHAR (create_date, 'YYYY') AS year_create,
         TO_CHAR (create_date, 'MM') AS month_create,
         TO_CHAR (create_date, 'WW') AS week_create,
         TO_CHAR (create_date, 'Q') AS quarter_create,
         TO_CHAR (resolved_date, 'YYYY') AS year_resolved,
         TO_CHAR (resolved_date, 'MM') AS month_resolved,
         TO_CHAR (resolved_date, 'WW') AS week_resolved,
         TO_CHAR (resolved_date, 'Q') AS quarter_resolved,
         item,
         site,
         status,
         contact_time,
         impact_label,
         (CASE
             WHEN item = '1' THEN 'a'
             WHEN item = '2' THEN 'b'
             WHEN item = '3' THEN 'c'
             ELSE NULL
          END)
            AS new_column_name
    FROM mytable
   WHERE create_date BETWEEN TO_DATE ('2013/03/01', 'YYYY/MM/DD')
                         AND TO_DATE ('2015/08/06', 'YYYY/MM/DD')
ORDER BY item, site, create_date;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you want

```
    select
       create_date
      ,resolved_date
      ,to_char(create_date, 'YYYY') as year_create
      ,to_char(create_date, 'MM') as month_create
      ,to_char(create_date, 'WW') as week_create
      ,to_char(create_date,'Q') as quarter_create
      ,to_char(resolved_date, 'YYYY') as year_resolved
      ,to_char(resolved_date, 'MM') as month_resolved
      ,to_char(resolved_date, 'WW') as week_resolved
      ,to_char(resolved_date,'Q') as quarter_resolved
      ,item
      ,site
      ,status
      ,contact_time
      ,impact_label
      ,(case item 
        when '1' then 'a'
        when '2' then 'b'
        when '3' then 'c'
        else null 
         end) as new_column_name 
  from mytable
 where create_date between to_date('2013/03/01','YYYY/MM/DD') 
                      and to_date('2015/08/06','YYYY/MM/DD')
 order by item, site, create_date;
```

I've removed the `group by` clause since you're not doing any sort of aggregation.  And since you apparently want the `case` statement to change the way that the `item` column is displayed, I moved that to the `select` list.

If that's not what you want, it would be very helpful if you would edit your question to include a test case.  Show us the table definition, show us the DML to insert a few rows, show us the result that you want, and show us the result that you're getting.